# Dialogflow API bearer token

Tags: google-oauth, dialogflow-es

How to I get a bearer dev-token for a Dialogflow v2 api call? I would like to run this command from my command-line interface on Mac osx.  An example request is below:

curl -X GET "https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects//agent/intents/?intentView=INTENT_VIEW_FULL" -H "Authorization: Bearer "

Answer (score 0):

There is a request example.

> curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
>   -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
>   "https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/{your-project-id}/agent/sessions/{session-id}>:detectIntent:detectIntent" \
>   --data "{'queryInput':{'event':{'name':'MY_CUSTOM_EVENT','parameters':{'parameter-name-1': 'parameter-value-1','parameter-name-2':'parameter-value-2',},'languageCode':'en-US'}}}"

For more requests to make, refer to [API reference](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent)

---

According to [Setting up authentication](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup), if you want to use v2 API call, you have to

1. Create the Service Account key.
2. Download the JSON key file.
3. Install and initialize the Cloud SDK.
4. Add an environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` (which the value is the path point to the JSON key file) to your shell.
5. You can test whether the Cloud SDK and variable is set up correctly by executing `echo $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)` in your console.
6. Then you should be able to make the request.

After making your request, you can navigate to the History tab in the Dialogflow console to check whether the request was successfully sent.

Comment: Step #3   Can i do it anywhere or just on the google cloud?  For example, can I do it on my macbook or ec2 ubuntu instance?

Comment: Yes, of course. Your can do it in any environment as long as it supports.

Comment: The point 3 is wrong. Install the whole 7.500+ files SDK just to make an API request to Dialogflow, while before on V1 any file was required, is of course the wrong way to do it in most cases. I'm still working on a solution that do not require to install the SDK.

Comment: when will token expire?